# how can i display a string in textView

Tags: iphone

i have got some data,i converted it into string but it is not displayed in textView..Can someone help me with this?This is what i have written....

aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

[mTextView setStringValue: aStr];

is there some other method to do this? mTextView is an outlet here of type NSTextView

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean it's an `UITextView`, in that case you can use `[mTextView setText:aStr]`.

If it's an `NSTextView` you can possibly use `[mTextView setString:aStr]` instead?

Comment: i have already tried [mTextView setText:aStr but it does not display the text.I am concerned with displaying and not storing..Plz guide me.

Comment: when i NSLog mTextiew.text.I am getting my desired data but why is it not displaying in textView